# CSGO server does not show in internet tab in community server browser

Tags: linux, networking, dedicated-server

I manage to install and run a CS:GO server on a proxmox vm. If i give the public ip (10.10.10.10:27015) to someone he can join and play, but no-one can see it in the community server browser.

This is how my network topology is

[image: My setup]

The VM is Ubuntu 22.04

Im running my server with this command:

./srcds_run -game csgo -tickrate 128 -console -usercon +net_public_adr 10.10.10.10 +ip 192.168.10.10 +port 27015 +game_type 1 +game_mode 0 +mapgroup mg_armsrace +map ar_shoots +sv_setsteamaccount STEAMPRIVATECODE -net_port_try 1

So can anyone help me make my server visible on Community server browser list.

Comment: I assume that 10.10.10.10 is a fake address, but is your _real_ public IP address also an 10.x?

Comment: i do not have number 10 in any of my ip's

Comment: Anyone with any ideas ?